# Why is exact matching in regular expressions ({n}) not working in command line?

Tags: regex, unix, command-line

I am trying to match an expression which occurs in a line exactly 2 times.
I tried:
`find . * | egrep "(prune){2}"`
This shows no output.

However, when I try:
`find . * | egrep "(prune){1}"`
It shows both 1 as well as 2 matches in the line.
[image: code+output]

Comment: Pictures of words are not very useful — it would be better if you had copied that text and pasted it as a code fragment or a blockquote.

Comment: If you can use GNU grep you could make use of `-P` and use a negative lookahead `find . * | grep -oP "^(?!(?:.*prune){3}).*prune.*prune.*"` to find exactly 2 matches.

Comment: Assuming that exactly two matches is a hard requirement, that is definitely a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{n}` syntax means: *match the previous expression n times*. So using `(prune){2}` will only ever match `pruneprune`.

Try `.*prune.*prune.*` instead.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I tried .+prune.+prune.+ which gave me exactly what I needed. But why does it list the entries twice for .*prune.*prune.* =>[link](https://imgur.com/a/d5jr5je)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it may be the way you're calling `find`. Try it as just `find . | egrep ...` (don't pass the `*` to `find`)

Answer (score 0):

For your case to use regex "(prune){2}" you need to find at least one file that contains the word "pruneprune" in the file name, you  dind't find nothing becasue you don't have file that contains "pruneprune" word.

to test it try to create some files with this :

```
touch {a..b}pruneprune{1..9}.log
```

and run your command with "(prune){2}" again.